# Angular 2 - Routing behaviour when refreshing

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am very new to Angular 2. And I have a doubt about routing, actually I am not understanding why this happens.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.template.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@RouteConfig([
  {path:'/index', name:'Index', component: IndexComponent, useAsDefault: true},
  {path:'/home', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent}
])
export class AppComponent { }
```

In the `IndexComponent` I have a button with the following attribute: `[routerLink]="['Home']"`

So, when I press it, the `HomeComponent` appears, as it is supossed to happen. The URL changes from `http://localhost/index` to `http://localhost/home` as expected.

The thing is that, if now I refresh the browser, it changes the url to `http://localhost/home/index` and shows me the index template. And if I refresh again the browser throws errors.

I did not read much, but I guess that I mustn't refresh the page `/home`, because Angular 2 can't know where to take me. Am I right? What should I do to take the user to `/index` if the he refresh the browser?

Answer (score 1):

You need either use HTML5 browser: [history management](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history) and configure your web server: [configure server for html5 mode](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode). Here is more info on that matter: [angular2 series routing](http://julienrenaux.fr/2015/12/25/angular2-series-routing/)

Or

Switch to hash location strategy:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})]);
```